# What is the source of charge developed on hair

Tags: electrostatics

I read that, dry hair develops charge as it doesn't have water to release the charge. I am not clear as what is the the source of the charge and how exactly water helps in maintaining the neutrality of hair.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the charge is [triboelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect): when unlike insulators (dielectrics) are rubbed together, electrons "prefer" one of the materials over the other.

When the hair is wet, the small amount of charge can find a path to ground (or, during rubbing, the charge immediately flows back to where it came from, using the water as a conductor). And it's only a tiny charge - as your hair has small capacitance, it takes very lilttle charge to build up 1000's of Volts of potential.